# grep a sentence from an SQL FIle

Tags: sql, ubuntu, grep

I have a very large SQL file and want to extract a single create statement from the file. THe command I use is;

```
cat dbdump.sql |grep "CREATE TABLE site_summaries" >newdump.sql
```

The problem with this approach is that the statemtn is spread over several lines and the grep only returns the first line. How do I continue the grep until it reaches a semi-colon denoting the end of the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your command has a "useless usage of cat", next time just do `grep '...' file` not `cat file|grep...`

grep does line wise checking. You can use awk to achieve that easily:

```
awk -v RS=';' '/CREATE TABLE site_summaries/' foo.sql
```

made a little test:

```
kent$  cat f
foo
bar;
this that;
CREATE TABLE site_summaries
whatever
else you need;
trash here....;

kent$  awk -v RS=';' '/CREATE TABLE site_summaries/' f

CREATE TABLE site_summaries
whatever
else you need
```

If you want the `;` still at the end of your extracted text, take this one:

```
awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=";\n" '/CREATE TABLE site_summaries/' file
```